# How do I listen for a click in a layer below (outside) a modal?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

Tl;dr
How do I listen for a click in a layer below?

[image]

[Youtube Video of problem in HD](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g41zsCijCF4)

Hello everyone,

I started yesterday with the dev.to app and now I'm facing an issue that is probably React Native specific.

If you click on your avatar in the top right corner of the dev.to app, a menu will open. Currently I have decided to use the modal brought by React Native.

```
import { Modal } from 'react-native';
```

I include it in the code as follows:

```
// TopBar.js
            <Modal
               transparent={true}
               visible={modalVisible}
               onRequestClose={() => {
                   Alert.alert('Modal has been closed.');
                   setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
               }}>
               <UserModal toggleFunction={setModalVisible} />
            </Modal>
```

and pass the current state via the toggleFuntion prop

```
const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
```

The content of the modal is structured as follows

```
    <View style={styles.centeredView}>
           <View style={styles.modalView}>
               <Text style={styles.userNameText}>Sebastian Richter</Text>
               <Text style={styles.userNicknameText}>@gismo1337</Text>
               <View style={styles.divider} />
               <Text style={styles.modalText}>Dashboard</Text>
               <Text style={styles.modalText}>Create Post</Text>
               <Text style={styles.modalText}>Reading list</Text>
               <Text style={styles.modalText}>Settings</Text>
               <View style={styles.divider} />
               <Text style={styles.modalText}>Sign Out</Text>
               {/* FIXME: For Development only */}
               <Pressable
                   style={[styles.button, styles.buttonClose]}
                   onPress={() => setModalVisible(false)}>
                   <Text style={styles.textStyle}>close - for develop only</Text>
               </Pressable>
           </View>
       </View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   centeredView: {
       alignItems: 'center',
       marginTop: 55,
   },
   modalView: {
       width: '95%',
       backgroundColor: '#161616',
       borderRadius: 5,
       borderWidth: 1,
       borderColor: '#363636',
       padding: 5,
       alignItems: 'flex-start',
       shadowColor: '#000',
       shadowOffset: {
           width: 0,
           height: 2,
       },
       shadowOpacity: 0.25,
       shadowRadius: 4,
       elevation: 5,
   },
   modalText: {
       color: 'white',
       marginBottom: 15,
       textAlign: 'center',
       paddingLeft: 15,
   },
   userNicknameText: {
       color: '#9C9C9C',
       marginBottom: 15,
       textAlign: 'center',
       paddingLeft: 15,
   },
   userNameText: {
       color: 'lightgray',
       textAlign: 'center',
       paddingLeft: 15,
   },
   divider: {
       borderBottomColor: '#363636',
       borderBottomWidth: 1,
       width: '100%',
       marginBottom: 20,
   }
});
```

Unfortunately, when the modal is open, I now have the problem that clicking on the avatar again is not noticed. This should cause the modal to close. However, my guess is that the "layer" of the ModalView is now over it and the click doesn't arrive.

**Q: Does anyone have an idea how I can sort of notice a click in a layer below?**

**Q: What advantages does the React Native modal bring that a view I have created myself does not have?**

**Repo:**

https://github.com/Gismo1337/dev-to-clone/blob/main/components/TopBar.js

https://github.com/Gismo1337/dev-to-clone/blob/main/components/UserModal.js